# Can I as a first level Magus use Spell Combat to swing my sword at one creature, then cast a spell to another (adjacent) one?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

The title pretty much says it all. Imagine I'm a first level magus, I am standing in a position with two goblins in front of me, one right in front, one next to him. Is it possible for me to use Spell Combat to first slash the goblin in front of me, and right after use shocking grasp on the one next to him? Or do both the attack and the spell have to be on the same creature?

Bonus question: Can I put a 5' step in the same turn after the attack/spell?
Extra bonus question: Can I use my Arcane pool to charge my weapon to a +1 in the same turn, before the attacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [D20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-):

> **Spell Combat (Ex)**
>
> At 1st level, a magus learns to cast spells and wield his weapons at the same time. **This functions much like two-weapon fighting**, but the off-hand weapon is a spell that is being cast. [...] **As a full-round action, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty and can also cast any spell from the magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action** [...]

It says nothing about both spell and melee attacks being against the same creature. And neither does [Two Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting), which this is a specialised form of. So, either attack can be against any valid target.

Spell Combat is a [Full-Round Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions). This means you can't take a Move Action or a Standard Action in the same round, but can take a 5-foot step, and can take a [Swift Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions), such as using your Arcane Pool.

You can take a [5-foot step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step) "before, during, or after your other actions in the round." eg, between the two attacks of Spell Combat.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear. I find it hard to assume something is allowed if it doesn't explicitely say so.

Comment: Spell combat is like TWF but is not bound by the rules of TWF beyond the analogy.